# Critique: Musically Inspired Brand Identity Design for a Freelancing Home Studio Music Producer

Tags: typography, logo, icon, critique, branding

My name is Kaitav Sapre and I am an independent home studio music producer. I am having a new logo designed for myself, but I am unsure about the type of logo I should consider getting designed, and what direction I should go with this.

By 'type of logo' I mean, should I go with a symbol/icon with my name, or should I go with my initials 'K' and'S'. Even just 'K' for the symbol and write my name beside it?

I'm lacking thoughts and guidance towards the right course of action. I am really confused and need some advice and direction on what logo would work well based on my name and what I do - music. I don't have much knowledge on typography.

- **Could anyone please give me some feedback on my logos?**
- **Do they suit an independent home studio music producer?**
- **What kind of logo would be most effective for a single person brand identity?**

Here are the current ideas I'm working with:

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Mr E. Upvoter: Thank you sir for improving/editing my post. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The benefit of having your full name in a logo is that, well, your name is the logo. Nike has the benefit of spending hundreds of millions of dollars to train the public to know that a "swoosh" = Nike, but you don't have that luxury. Not yet, anyways!

While using initials or symbols in logos can sometimes lead to more creative solutions or more distinctive marks, for smaller entities I do think it's best to use your name as part of the logo. Otherwise, as you said, you'll have to include your name anyways, and it won't look as cool.

So, even though both logo concepts aren't all that strong (though the first one is much better executed than the second), I like the idea of the first one better because your name stands out and there's a mark associated with it as a secondary element.

Comment: Hi Brendon, thanks for your thoughtful & helpful suggestions. The reason for having the mark, I was/am thinking, is just to use it as a standlone on profile pics on social networking websites, music websites, on the music album front cover, etc(like Nike mark) If I use the first logo or similar, I am confused as to how I would put it to use. Profile pic is fine, but on front album cover, should I put the "full logo with symbol" as the composer or just simply my name? There is some unclarity on this front for me. This is not the right place to clarify, I know, but wanted to share the thoughts.

Comment: However, I fully agree with you that for someone like me who is just starting having full name is logo rather than just a symbol makes more sense. This is something which I did not realize before.

Answer (score 2):

this question is like "how should my logo look like?" my advice would be to hire a designer/design studio to do it for you or just start start sketching all of your ideas out. there is little reason to choose a text only logo before sketching out all of the above. Also look at what other bands/music makers have in their style and maybe try to fit in.

Comment: Hi Shubb, thanks for your suggestions. I have attached the two logos I got from two different designers on fiverr.com. Yes, I am looking at different music artists logos to get some idea, but I still don't see the 'exact'direction for my logo.

Comment: Those logos are GREAT. Well, great for $5. I think Shubb is suggesting you consider investing more than $5 in your brand identity, though. I tend to agree.

Comment: Hi DA01, thanks for your comment. Okay, I understand it now. Do you know any other resources or websites where I can find better designers? I cannot afford more than $100 though, since I am just starting out and cannot say that I can make good returns from my music. Actually, everything I am doing is without expecting any returns and it is all a kind of investment, because music is my passion and I believe I should not think of "making money" from music at this stage. However, I want to do it as professionally as I can and therefore, the need for a logo. :)

Answer (score 1):

I very recently made a music logo, but for a different purpose (business, website and app). I think I can add some things I picked up during the whole process. I went through maybe 20 iterations, and the last iteration included rebuilding it and incorporating the Golden Ratio into it as much as I could, it actually pulled off the effect I was imagining much better than trying to draw it randomly. Unfortunately I can't show you that logo right now, it's top secret :P.

Anyway, I agree with everything Brendan has said, and I'd like to reiterate what he said: **including your full name will be much more effective**.

Having a symbol as a secondary brand asset is also handy, but you will almost always want it to be accompanied by your name - to make certain that people know what you can do, and tell it to others.

So my first conclusion is straightforward; use a logo that includes your full name for everything except those rad stickers that you put on your speakers; those can be the secondary asset only if you really want it somewhere. :)

On the same note, the name must always draw the main focus, so don't have a big symbol floating over tiny type! (I know you didn't, it's just a gentle reminder not to as you continue).

Now, on the secondary asset, I like the squiggly line sound wave, it's within the vicinity of what I settled on for my logo. Because of this, I'm going to see if I can apply the Golden Ratio to it the same way I did with mine.

Result of my first and only attempt, a sound wave that increases by roughly Golden Proportions, personally I think it makes for a much more interesting shape:

[image][image]

[image][image]

I had to replace that 'R', as it really bugs me. I just copy and pasted the 'P' over it.

The shape can be executed much better, but I was trying to do it quickly not perfectly. I honestly think that using the Golden Ratio on an otherwise fairly standard shape can really give it some interest.

So in conclusion, I advise you to create a full name logo for primary use, and then work more on the sound wave concept for a secondary asset. Think about or instruct a designer to think about incorporating the golden ratio, and geometric inspirations.

Even something this simple can be incredibly complex to create. Anyway, for your reference if you want to take this further, it should give you a general idea of the approach for creating this shape, I did some of the maths but it should be worked out completely mathematically for the best finish:

[image]

I hope I've helped you to find some direction, and you achieve what you're after.

Comment: E.Upvoter: Thanks a lot for detailed & helpful inputs. I also like what you have designed. I've got the basic essence of the everyone's opinion. However, I am confused with only one thing - logo usage. If you read my reply to Brendan, I have mentioned this concern. Is there a real significance of having a standalone symbol? If not, why and how would a 'symbol in text logo' be used?

One more question on 'name-based-logo':
Should I consider full name in the logo or just the first name, as I think first name is unique & more memorable?
Some advice/thoughts on all this would make it all clear. :)

Comment: Your first name may be relatively unique, but how many Kaitav's will I find if I Google only your first name? Until you're a superstar you need to keep telling them your name until they remember it and support you towards superstardom - so your full name practically everywhere is my advice. The symbol should be little more than an embellishment to add visual interest and create a unique and memorable shape **with** the text. You could use it alone, for contexts where you can't fit your name, like favicons, and anything else very small but as a rule, you're name is the most important element.

Comment: Yeah, you are quite correct. Thanks for helping me understand the advantages of having name as the key element of the logo. I was lacking this very direction, and now I get the benefits of it. I think I will have to consider getting the symbol made minimalistic at the same time a symbol which slowly starts to develop its own identity. And I can do this by putting that symbol somewhere in the corner of my front music album cover - but of course the "name-symbol actual logo" will be highlighted with the album name.

Thanks everyone for your help, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: And by the way, why cannot I mark more than one answer as correct? :)

Comment: E. Upvoter: One personal question, if you do not mind. Are you into logo designing? If so, and you are interested in designing one for me, can I contact you out of this forum? Budget is a constraint for me to be honest, but we can still discuss if you are interested and have time. :)

Comment: @EUpvoter: Okay, got your point. Thanks a lot. You may delete the comment now (just logged in to my PC, hence the delay). I will give a detailed thought and send you an email.